# How do I raise PermissionDenied Redirect to another page using CBV?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have a model with my permissions, and in my view using CBV(generic.CreateView) or (generic.DetailView), if a user logged has permissions, he can access the view, if hasn't access, the page Forbidden 403 shows.

But, if a user dont have permission for that view, I want raise exception PermissionDenied, and redirect to a specific page for this error.

My view:

```
class AddJob(LoginRequiredMixin, PermissionRequiredMixin, generic.CreateView)

   permission required = 'can_create_job'
   model = Job
   fields = ['name', 'description', 'salary']
   success_url = reversy_lazy('job_list)
   context_object_name = 'object_name'
```

Can anyone help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is to add `raise_exception = True` to view class, this will raise `PermissionDenied`, i.e. return response with 403 (Forbidden) http status. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.AccessMixin.raise_exception

Also, if you want to show your own 403 page, you can create `403.html` template, django will use it when returning 403. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/views/#the-403-http-forbidden-view

Comment: It works with the both. raise_exception = True, and I created 403.html file and put my informations about PermissionDenied. Thanks a lot my friend.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, you can't do both ***redirection*** and ***raise 404 exception***.
That is, you could ***either*** redirect to some page if the user has no permission ***or*** raise an exception.
**Case 1 : raise an exception**
to raise the exception, you should add **`raise_exception = True`** in your view class as,

```
class AddJob(LoginRequiredMixin, PermissionRequiredMixin, generic.CreateView):
    permission_required = 'can_create_job'
    model = Job
    fields = ['name', 'description', 'salary']
    success_url = reversy_lazy('job_list')
    context_object_name = 'object_name'
    raise_exception = True # Change is here
```

**Case 2 : redirect to specific page**
Set **`login_url`** in your view,

```
class AddJob(LoginRequiredMixin, PermissionRequiredMixin, generic.CreateView):
    permission_required = 'can_create_job'
    model = Job
    fields = ['name', 'description', 'salary']
    success_url = reversy_lazy('job_list')
    context_object_name = 'object_name'
    login_url = '/path/to/specific/page'
```

### What will happen if you set both `login_url` and `raise_exception` ?

The [**`AccessMixin`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.AccessMixin) class has a method [**`handle_no_permission()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.AccessMixin.handle_no_permission) which is being called to handle this condition.

> [**Source Code**](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/mixins.py#L41)
>
> ```
> def handle_no_permission(self):
>     if self.raise_exception:
>         raise PermissionDenied(self.get_permission_denied_message())
>     return redirect_to_login(self.request.get_full_path(), self.get_login_url(), self.get_redirect_field_name())
> ```

Here you can see, if you set **`raise_exception = True`**, ***django won't consider the `login_url`***

Comment: can I create a specifc html for message 403? like, 'no_permission.html', and set to login_url = 'no_permission.html'?

Comment: Yes, its woks. I created a file 403.html, and put my informations about the page for PermissionDenied, and I used raise_exception = True. Thanks a lot my friend.

Comment: @MatheusSoares- I am trying to follow the **2nd Option**, however can't figure out the last part i.e. `login_url`. How to get the page to display **custom message**. Thanks.

Comment: Got it to work. However not able to **send the permission values to the template** as context. Any suggestions?There are certain guidance in Django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/class-based-views/#subclassing-generic-views) however not sure how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of things addressed here, but just thought I'd add some options:

I you want full control in some standardized way for different views, you can create your own mixing by subclassing Django's:

```
class MyAccessMixin(AccessMixin):
    """ A custom AccessMixing to handle access denied from PermissionRequired """
    permission_denied_message = "Oupsies! You do not have access!"

    def handle_no_permission(self):
        messages.info(self.request ,self.permission_denied_message)
        # or specific redirects based on context 
        return redirect(reverse_lazy(self.my_perm_denied_url_string))
```

Assuming the url you redirect to displays messages from the framework, it'll show to users.

And of course you'd add the mixin to your views, e.g.:

```
class AddJob(LoginRequiredMixin, PermissionRequiredMixin, MyAccessMixin, generic.CreateView):
    # code
```